# Databricks LEFT function not returning any data

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I appear to have implemented the LEFT function with Databricks incorrectly (it works perfectly fine with MS SQL).
I get null with Databricks

```
select category_list 
,LEFT(organizations.category_list, CHARINDEX(',', organizations.category_list + ',') - 1) AS `category CB`
from basecrmcbreport.organizations
```

The output I'm getting is:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I should be implementing the LEFT function with Databricks

Comment: Could you check what ```CHARINDEX(',', organizations.category_list + ',') - 1)``` returns first?

Comment: Hi Robert, I get the following ```mismatched input ')' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 2, pos 54)```

Comment: Excuse me, I meant ```CHARINDEX(',', organizations.category_list + ',')```

Comment: Hi @RobertKossendey, thanks for getting in touch. I managed to get in working with the following ```,case when charindex(',',category_list) > 0 then left(category_list,charindex(',',category_list)-1) else category_list end as `category CB````

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the query that you are using is using `+` to concatenating. Using the following query itself is returning null, where I tried concatenating `,` to column using `+` operator.

```
select *,(category_list+',') as using_plus from demo
```

[image]

- Instead of using plus (+) operator to concatenate, you can use `concat()` function. I modified the query as follows and got the expected result.

```
select category_list 
,LEFT(category_list, CHARINDEX(',', concat(category_list,',')) - 1) AS `category CB`
from demo
```

[image]

- Using alternate approach as **suggested by @Patterson**, `CASE` has also given the same output:

```
select category_list, case when charindex(',',category_list) > 0 then left(category_list,charindex(',',category_list)-1) else category_list end as `category CB` from demo
```

[image]